# what would be the time complexity of this recursive solution

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was trying to solve the word-break problem this is a solution that I have come up with but I am not sure about the time complexity.
can someone help me?

**Problem statement** :-
Given a string s and a dictionary of strings wordDict, return true if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

**Note** that the same word in the dictionary may be reused multiple times in the segmentation.

soln:-

```
bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
        int n = s.size();
        if(n == 0){
            return true;
        }
        if(find(wordDict.begin(),wordDict.end(),s) != wordDict.end()){
            return true;
        }
        
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            if((find(wordDict.begin(),wordDict.end(),s.substr(0,i)) != wordDict.end()) && 
                wordBreak(s.substr(i),wordDict)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am considering each prefix here and then searching it in the dictionary if it is present in the dictionary I am making a recursive call for the rest of the string (or suffix). if the recursive call for suffix returns true. I return true. otherwise, I try for the next prefix. and if I have tried all the prefixes and none of them resulted in a solution. I return false.

Comment: Not sure if the actual limit is worse, but the worst case cannot be better than the number of ordered partitions of the input string size - 1. (Dictionary: `a,aa,aaa, ...`; Input: `aaaaa...aab`)

Comment: Btw: Just to give you an idea of how bad this is let's consider a string of `2*n` `a` chars followed by one `b` and a dictionary containing only `a` and `aa`. The `a`s require you to choose at least `n` times between the 2 possible words in the dictionary, i.e. there are more than `2^n` possible choices before you finally get to check for a match in the dictionary for `b`...

Comment: I did solve the question by using dp but this was my brute force approach I got TLE for this but was giving the right answer for custom inputs. I think the time complexity for recursion would be 2^n but I am confused because of find() function and substr() function as their complexities are O(log n)  and  O(n) respectively. so that's why I wanna know how these two will affect the overall time complexity and what would that full-time complexity be.